# How to resolve "import error" while running import torchvision?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

While trying to run "import torchvision", the following error displayed-

```
ImportError: /home/jupyterlab/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/_C.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6caffe26detail36_typeMetaDataInstance_preallocated_7E
```

This did not help either-
! conda install pytorch=1.11.0 torchvision=0.12.0 -c pytorch -y

Answer (score 0):

pip install torchvision==0.4.1 solves the problem